# Did Salesforce acquire gravitytank this year?

Tags: untagged

Salesforce has just acquired Twin Prime, according to [Business insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/salesforce-acquired-twin-prime-startup-2016-12/?international=true&r=US)

And [Crunchbase](https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/salesforce/acquisitions).

This is the 10th acquisition of the year. However, I do think [Salesforce has also acquired gravitytank this year](http://web.archive.org/web/20160916072051/http://www.gravitytank.com/blog/gravitytank-will-join-Salesforce) but it is missing from the list.

Can I get it confirmed that it is actually the 11th acquisition this year? I am about to write a blog about this so I just want to be accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Gravity Tank was acquired by Salesforce as the annoucements mean it must be official even if the deal hasn't completed yet.

[Gravity Tank blog](http://www.gravitytank.com/blog/gravitytank-will-join-Salesforce)

Nice [infographic](http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-2016-acquisitions-infographic/) at Salesforce Ben's site with all this years acquisitions by Salesforce.

Comment: Thank you for this. The infographic is awesome. I have also generated a similar blog about it which contains a bit more information: http://sfdcinpractice.com/index.php/2016/12/15/salesforce-acquisitions-2016/